# Encode string to Base64 in Inno Setup (Unicode Version of Inno Setup)

Tags: base64, inno-setup, pascal, freepascal, pascalscript

**Problem**

I tried to use the Pascal function `EncodeStringBase64`, assuming Inno Setup had access to the Pascal standard library but it fails to find it and provides an `Unknown Identifier` error.

https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/base64/encodestringbase64.html

I also found this code to carry out the conversion but it seems to be restricted to AnsiStrings.

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/windows/base64.iss

**Question**

Ideally I'd like to use the standard library function, is there any way that I can access it?

If not, is the code using AnsiStrings safe to use on normal Unicode strings if I change the signature?

I'm going to  carry out testing for it, but I'm worried that I'll test a good number of use cases, but this wouldn't guarantee that it's actually suitable for *every* character, and edge cases may exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 encodes **bytes**, not **characters** (strings). That's also probably the reason, why the `Encode64` implementation, that you have found, takes `AnsiString`. `AnsiString` is commonly (ab)used in Inno Setup Pascal Script as a dynamic array of **bytes**. While `string` is an array of **characters**.

If you want to encode a string, you first have to represent the string as an array of bytes (in a way the recipient of the Base64-encoded string expects it) and then you can use your `Encode64` implementation.

In case you encode ASCII characters only, you can just blindly cast `string` to `AnsiString`. If you use non-ascii characters, you will probably want to convert your `UnicodeString` to bytes using some encoding, like UTF-8.

As for the resulting string, you can just safely cast it from `AnsiString` to `string`, as Base64 uses ASCII characters only (though, it also makes sense to change function signature to return `string`, as it indeed *returns* a character  string, not byte array).

So for an ASCII input, this will do:

```pascal
Base64 := string(Encode64(AnsiString(S)));
```

---

If you want to use a "standard" function, you can use [`CryptBinaryToString` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringw). Though that won't spare you from solving the above, as the function takes an array of bytes on input (as expected).

---

*The above makes a difference only, if you use Unicode Inno Setup (what you correctly do). Had you used Ansi Inno Setup (what you should not), `string` is `AnsiString`.*